# How to share data from host to containers using named volumes?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I'm trying to share code from host to `php` and `nginx` containers. Here is my `docker-compose.yml`:

```yaml
version: "3"
services:
  php:
    image: php:fpm
    container_name: php
    ports:
      - 9000:9000
    volumes: 
      - php_data:/var/www/html/

      # configs
      - ./php/config:/usr/local/etc/php

  nginx:
    image: nginx 
    ports:
      - 80:80
    volumes:
      - php_data:/var/www/html

      # logs
      - ./nginx/logs:/var/log/nginx

      # configs
      - ./nginx/config/default.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf:ro
      - ./nginx/config/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf:ro

volumes:
  php_data:
    ./code
```

The error when running `docker-compose up` is:

> ERROR: In file './docker-compose.yml', volume 'php_data' must be a
>   mapping not a string.

How do I make make docker-compose know, that I need `./code` shared with both `nginx` and php `containers`?

Comment: Its not the answer to your question but if it is enough for you to share the volume between the containers and not the host you could remove the last line "./code" as seen in the [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#volume-configuration-reference)

Answer (score 0):

Docker saying it needs a mapping, so you need to set something like ./code:{map} in your volume

I think you have 2 options here. Since you share the code map to /var/www/html on both containers.

**Option 1**
Set the /var/www/html map in your volume:

```
volumes:
  php_data:
    ./code:/var/www/html
```

then change /var/www/html to / in your containers.

**Option 2**

```
volumes:
  php_data:
    ./code:/
```

Comment: With `then change /var/www/html to / in your containers.` you mean changing the lines inside `docker-compose.yml`? i.e. `volumes: - php_data:/`?